# how to use wget with Julia

Tags: python-3.x, julia

I am interested in loading a file:

url: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data

I am wondering if there is an option equivalent to !wget which can be used in python to load the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run any shell command, you use `run` as described [here.](http://blog.leahhanson.us/post/julia/julia-commands.html) If you want to read the file into Julia, then [`DelimitedFiles` is your friend.](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/DelimitedFiles/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of Python's `wget` in Julia is `download`

To get the file to your disk just run:

```
download("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data","./autofile.txt")
```

Do not use `run` for this because you take a risk that your code will not be portable.

Comment: Note that, as stated in its documentation, [Base.download](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.download) "relies on the availability of external tools such as `curl`, `wget` or `fetch` to download the file and is provided for convenience. For production use or situations in which more options are needed, please use a package that provides the desired functionality instead."

Comment: You are right, but as of today `curl` is part of Windows 10, you also have it on MacOS and is present in any user-friendly Linux installation. So unless you are running some very exotic operating system you can safely assume it to work (as far as I remember `download` works even on Crays). Hence this is what I would recommend for daily data science tasks. For writing production libraries indeed `HTTP.jl` is the correct approach.

Answer (score 3):

In order to download files, I tend to use the following helper function, which is fully implemented in Julia, does not rely on the availability of external tools, and is therefore entirely portable across systems (it does, however, depend on [`HTTP.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl)):

```
import HTTP

function http_download(url, dest)
    HTTP.open(:GET, url) do http
        open(dest, "w") do file
            write(file, http)
        end
    end
end

http_download("http://www.julialang.org/", "/tmp/index.html")
```